# How do go from a single light/fan bathroom switch to a double paddle with no ground or hot wire?

Tags: wiring, lighting, ground

The old switch had just 2 side wires, one for the fan and one for the light. There was no ground of hot.

I'm installing a legrand radiant 2 in 1 paddle switch, and it's not working. I'm assuming that's because there's no ground of hot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does that switch have a screw in the middle between the two wires?  That doens't look like a normal switch.

Comment: Looks like a 3-way switch, with the black screw.

Comment: Was the old switch a dual switch, or a single?  Did you have separate control of fan and light before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a three wire out to fan.  Then the black screw gets line in from the panel,the other wire is load out to ,fan light. And only works both together.  3 wire lets them be separate .  White is neutral, on the other screws, black to light red to fan. Need 3 wire to do this. Or leave in a single switch and both run like they did before.

Comment: On a 3 way that would be one or the other always on, a double switch on a single yoke with 3 wire would do it though.